# Program that checks for duplicated characters in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I have been trying to make a program that gets an array from the user and checks if the are any duplicated characters next to each other in it and if there are, the program asks the user to enter the array again but for some reason my program only asks the user to enter the array once.

```
    printf("Please enter your private password: ");
    fgets(pass, MAX_LEN, stdin);

    for (i = 0; i < strlen(pass - 1); i++) {
        if (pass[i] == pass[i + 1]) {
            printf("You entered duplicated numbers! \n");
            printf("Please enter your private password: ");
            fgets(pass, MAX_LEN, stdin);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `strlen(pass-1)` --> `strlen(pass) - 1`. And your *duplicate* checks only consecutive dups? If you read `pass` again, the index `i` doesn't start from `0` again.

Comment: @l3x Weird, now it doesn't work at all. The programs asks the user to enter the array but don't print "You entered duplicated number! \n"

Answer (score 5):

The code snippet can look the following way

```
char *p = NULL;
do
{
    printf( "Please enter your private password: " );
    if ( ( p = fgets( pass, MAX_LEN, stdin ) ) != NULL )
    {
        while ( *p && *p != *( p + 1 ) ) ++p;  

        if ( *p != '\0' )
        {
            printf("You entered duplicated numbers! \n");
            p = NULL;
        }
    }
} while ( p == NULL );
```

Or it can be written like

```
int valid = 0;

do
{
    char *p = pass;

    printf( "Please enter your private password: " );

    if ( !fgets( pass, MAX_LEN, stdin ) ) break;

    while ( *p && *p != *( p + 1 ) ) ++p;  

    valid = *p == '\0';
    if ( !valid  )
    {
        printf("You entered duplicated numbers! \n");
    }
} while ( !valid );
```

Comment: Can you please teach me what is the program?
what is '*' in the '*p', and what '!*p' means?

Comment: Vlad, the while checks that characters are identical. Shouldn't that be `!=` and then `if (*p)...`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I have already tried several times to write a valid code.:)

Comment: @OfekEzon *p is the same as p[0] and *( p + 1 ) is the same as p[1].

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry for bothering you, but if *p equals to NULL so what is p[1]? and what is '!p[0]' ?

Comment: Vlad, now fix the `if (!*p)`, which checks the loop reached the end (no duplicates) into `if (*p)` which checks the loop exited before the end (seen a duplicate).

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is:

```
char    * GetStrPtr;        //  pointer return value for get string
bool    InvPwd = true;      //  flag for invalid password; true to force execution of while

printf("Please enter your private password: ");
GetStrPtr = fgets(pass, MAX_LEN, stdin);
while (GetStrPtr != NULL && pass[0] != '\0'  && InvPwd == true) {

    InvPwd = false;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(pass) - 1; i++)
        if (pass[i] == pass[i + 1]) {
            printf("You entered duplicated numbers! \n");
            printf("Please enter your private password: ");
            GetStrPtr = fgets(pass, MAX_LEN, stdin);
            InvPwd = true;
            break;
        }
}
```

As others pointed out, the problem was with `strlen(pass - 1);`.  Also, I believe the `else` with the `i++` would cause you to skip characters.  You don't need that because the `for` statement takes care of the increment.

Answer (score 0):

You pass an invalid pointer to `strlen`: `pass - 1` points before the array.  You should instead use `strlen(pass) - 1`.

To re-prompt the user for the array, you should have a separate loop to read the password and to check for duplicate characters:

Here is a corrected version:

```
for (;;) {
    printf("Please enter your private password: ");
    if (!fgets(pass, MAX_LEN, stdin)) {
        /* end if file reached */
        return -1;
    }
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; pass[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (pass[i] == pass[i + 1])
            break;
        }
    }
    if (pass[i]) {
        printf("You entered duplicated numbers! \n");
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```